Google login popup covers login area on mobile
I recently had to change my password, which led me to log into the site on mobile, which I haven’t had to do in a while. I noticed that the “Sign in with Google” completely covers the regular login area. Interestingly, this is not the case when logging into Meta, but seems to be the case for all of the regular sites (I tested Physics and Stack Overflow, but am reasonably confident it isn’t limited to them).
Screenshots on iPhone Xs, in Firefox Focus, but first noticed the issue in Safari (switched to the other browser so I could take screenshots without having to log out then in to ask the question):



Is this intentional behavior? And if so, why is MSE’s login page the outlier here?
Normally it would be be that annoying but for reasons, logging in on one site didn’t log me in to all of them, so I had to close the same dang popup like 6 different times.

But you can just click it away, right? Like any popup? I believe this Sign in with Google popup appears similarly on most sites that have that .."functionality".

@Joachim sure, but having to do so repeatedly gets a tad annoying. Also I’m curious as to why it’s not there on the MSE login page, but is there on all the other login pages. Plus, “log in with Google” is already on the page, the popup is unnecessary.

There's currently an experiment on sign-up features on [insert sites here] related to "Google one-tap", I wonder if this is related.

@Joachim even if it can be dismissed, it means extra step, i.e. make login more complicated. People want to see a clean login screen, where they can just give credentials and login, without having to close popups and perform more actions. It's a bad user experience.

@ShadowWizard I definitely agree (and hate seeing this Google login modal pop up everywhere), but my point was that this doesn't seem to be a SE-specific problem (let alone a bug).

@Joachim the fact that it’s inconsistent across sites is what I’d consider the bug.

Well it's just in A/B testing phase, when it's done it would be rolled to all sites and will be consistent. But I do consider it a UX bug, as it's against common sense, hence a bug. The fact other sites also work this way doesn't mean otherwise.
